# iText PDF: the document has no pages

Tags: java, sql, pdf, itext

I'm trying to do a date range based filter to export a report into a PDF; however, when I click to export the PDF, I get the following message:
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
Here's my PDF class' code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PDFPrinter {
    private String date1;
    private String date2;
    public void printpdf(){
    try {
            
            String file_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
            String file_place = "C:\\";
            String file_name_and_place = "C:\\File\\" + file_name + ".pdf";
            Document document = new Document();           
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file_name_and_place));
            document.open();
            ConnectionFactory myConn = new ConnectionFactory();
            Connection connection = myConn.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_pacientes";
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(rs.getString("UID")+" "+rs.getString("Name")+" "+rs.getString("Address")+" "+rs.getString("Age")+" "+rs.getString("Frontline")+" "+rs.getString("VaccinationDate")+" "+rs.getString("Priority"));
                document.add(para);
                document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
                
            }
            document.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seu arquivo foi criado com sucesso em "+file_name_and_place);
        }         
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente, por favor.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    public void printPDFWithFilter(String date1, String date2){
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
        ConnectionFactory factory= new ConnectionFactory();
        try(Connection c = factory.getConnection()){
            String file_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
            String file_place = "C:\\";
            String file_name_and_place = "C:\\File\\" + file_name + ".pdf";
            Document document = new Document();           
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file_name_and_place));
            document.open();
            ConnectionFactory myConn = new ConnectionFactory();
            Connection connection = myConn.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_pacientes WHERE VaccinationDate BETWEEN ? AND ?";
                         
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, "%" +date1+ "%");
            ps.setString(2, "%" +date2+ "%");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();            
            while(rs.next()){
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);        
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(rs.getString("UID")+" "+rs.getString("Name")+" "+rs.getString("Address")+" "+rs.getString("Age")+" "+rs.getString("Frontline")+" "+rs.getString("VaccinationDate")+" "+rs.getString("Priority"));
                document.add(para);
                document.add(new Paragraph(" "));                
            }
            document.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seu arquivo foi criado com sucesso em "+file_name_and_place);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            String sStackTrace = sw.toString(); 
            System.out.println(sStackTrace);
            if (sStackTrace == "ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages."){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Selecione as datas novamente; com as configurações atuais, o documento não teria páginas.");
            }
            else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao filtrar o PDF; por favor, tente novamente.");  
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the PDF generation button:

```
   private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  String date1 = jDateChooser1.getDate().toString();
  String date2 = jDateChooser2.getDate().toString();
  PDFPrinter pdfp = new PDFPrinter();
  pdfp.printPDFWithFilter(date1, date2);
    }
```

I believe there's a problem with SQL and JDateChooser, since its date format appears to be incompatible with SQL's DATE format, but I'm not sure about it and I haven't found any ways to change it, so, I'm here looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that your SQL request doesn't return any row,
2. Put your PdfTable(3) out of your while();

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to solve the question with the help of bigtheo's answer and a little bit of perseverance haha; well, the problem was on the percentage symbols on the priority list inside the second method. I just erased them and it worked!